# Javascript form validation. No error message. No popup

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help getting JS form validation working.

I have form rules in a .js script file I've linked to in the html head.

Example of for rule:

```
    function IsValid4DigitZip( str ) {
    // Return immediately if an invalid value was passed in
    if (str+"" == "undefined" || str+"" == "null" || str+"" == "")  
        return false;

    var isValid = true;

    str += "";

    // Rules: zipstr must be 5 characters long, and can only contain numbers from
   // 0 through 9
   if (IsBlank(str) || (str.length != 4) || !IsInt(str, false))
        isValid = false;

   return isValid;
} // end IsValid4DigitZip
```

This is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>orderbooks</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="datavalidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
function validate(orderbooks){
var digits="0123456789" 
var temp 

if ( IsValid4DigitZip(document.orderbooks.Postcode.value) ) {
  // Zip code is valid
} else {
alert("Invalid postcode:)
  // Zip code is invalid
}
return true 
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="orderbooks" onSubmit="return validate(orderbooks)" >
    Name: <input type="text" size="20" name="Name">
    Street Number:  <input type="text" size="5" name="streetnumber" maxlength="5">
    Street Name: <input type="text" size="20" name="streetname" maxlength="25">
    Postcode: <input type="text" size="4" name="postcode" maxlength="4">
    Telephone: <input type="text" size="11" name="telephone" maxlength="11">
    Email: <input type="text" size="20" name="email" maxlength="50">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear the Form">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't get it to show the alert or warning.

OK I got the postcode to work with a error message! I have another question.

If I wanted to add this form validation rule:

```
    function IsNum( numstr ) {
    // Return immediately if an invalid value was passed in
    if (numstr+"" == "undefined" || numstr+"" == "null" || numstr+"" == "") 
        return false;

    var isValid = true;
    var decCount = 0;       // number of decimal points in the string

    // convert to a string for performing string comparisons.
    numstr += "";   

    // Loop through string and test each character. If any
    // character is not a number, return a false result.
    // Include special cases for negative numbers (first char == '-')
    // and a single decimal point (any one char in string == '.').   
    for (i = 0; i < numstr.length; i++) {
        // track number of decimal points
        if (numstr.charAt(i) == ".")
            decCount++;

        if (!((numstr.charAt(i) >= "0") && (numstr.charAt(i) <= "9") || 
                (numstr.charAt(i) == "-") || (numstr.charAt(i) == "."))) {
        isValid = false;
        break;
        } else if ((numstr.charAt(i) == "-" && i != 0) ||
                (numstr.charAt(i) == "." && numstr.length == 1) ||
              (numstr.charAt(i) == "." && decCount > 1)) {
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }                                
//if (!((numstr.charAt(i) >= "0") && (numstr.charAt(i) <= "9")) || 
   } // END for   

    return isValid;
}  // end IsNum
```

Would I add it by typing this in the html directly under the first function rule:

```
     if (IsNum(document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=postcode]")[0].value)) {
    // Zip code is valid
  } else {
    alert("Postcode invalid! Please use only numbers:");
    return false;
  }
```

Is that how I would do this?

Comment: I see an error in `alert("Invalid postcode:)`, have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: First Check the console.it's giving error.

Second name of postcode is name="postcode"(small p) and you are trying to get it with (capital P).

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in your code:

1. Alert is missing double quotes.
2. The postcode value sent to `IsValid4DigitZip` is wrong.

Replace

`document.orderbooks.Postcode.value`

with

`document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=postcode]")[0].value`

Updated `validate` function code:

```
function validate(orderbooks) {
  var digits = "0123456789"
  var temp

  if (IsValid4DigitZip(document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=postcode]")[0].value)) {
    // Zip code is valid
  } else {
    alert("Invalid postcode:");
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

```js
 function validate(orderbooks) {
      var digits = "0123456789"
      var temp

      if (IsValid4DigitZip(document.orderbooks.querySelectorAll("[name=postcode]")[0].value)) {
        // Zip code is valid
      } else {
        alert("Invalid postcode:");
        return false;
      }
      return true
    }

    function IsValid4DigitZip(str) {
      // Return immediately if an invalid value was passed in
      if (str + "" == "undefined" || str + "" == "null" || str + "" == "")
        return false;

      var isValid = true;

      str += "";

      // Rules: zipstr must be 5 characters long, and can only contain numbers from
      // 0 through 9
      if ((str.trim().length != 4) || !isNumeric(str.trim()))
        isValid = false;

      return isValid;
    } // end IsValid4DigitZip

    //Check for numbers
    function isNumeric(n) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
```

```html
<form name="orderbooks" onSubmit="return validate(orderbooks)">
  Name: <input type="text" size="20" name="Name"> Street Number: <input type="text" size="5" name="streetnumber" maxlength="5">    Street Name: <input type="text" size="20" name="streetname" maxlength="25"> Postcode: <input type="text" size="4" name="postcode"
    maxlength="4"> Telephone: <input type="text" size="11" name="telephone" maxlength="11"> Email: <input type="text" size="20"
    name="email" maxlength="50">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear the Form">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

Comment: It's still not showing the alert message popup with your code.

Comment: @c0nfus3d You can see the running example above. Click on `Submit` button without entering `Postal Code` and prompt is displayed. I am not sure of what you have written for `IsBlank` and `IsInt`. You may want to check the logic for those.

Comment: OK I got it to give a error message. can you look at my latest post and give feedback :) Thanks :)

Comment: @c0nfus3d  Updated my code above. The validation works now for blank postal code. The postal code should contain 4 digits.

Comment: OK it works. How would you use multiple functions within the same html?

Comment: @c0nfus3d If your first issue solved, please accept the answer and raise a new question with the problem/issue, so that you can get proper help from the community.